# Solution to the second order differential equation of $LCR$ series circuit.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When applying Kirchoff's voltage law to a $\text{LCR}$ series circuit. The following differential equation pops up..

$$E\sin(Kt)-\dfrac{q}{C}-R\dfrac{dq}{dt}-L\dfrac{d^2q}{dt^2}=0$$

Where 
$E$, $K$, $R$, $C$ and $L$ are positive constants.

I tried solving the equation by assuming the solution to be of the form $A\sin(Bx)+C\cos(Dx)$ and then solving for the constants but it didn't work.

I'm in 12th grade and only know how to solve differential equations like linear first degree.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are acquainted with complex numbers.

These type of equations are easily solved (electrical engineers know very well) in the complex field.

Pass from $E\sin(Kt)$ to $V=E e^{iKt}$, and also express $q=Q e^{iK(t+\tau)}$, or better just $q=Q e^{iKt}$, allowing $Q$ to be complex .
To take the derivatives is easy, and you  arrive to a complex equation to be solved for $Q$ and which is linear in $V$ ($V$ divided by a complex expression in $R,L,C$).

In that, take the immaginary component of both sides, and that's all.